# How can I have IE recognize UTF-8 documents without BOM?

Tags: internet-explorer, encoding, utf-8

```
<html lang="ko">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html: charset=utf-8">.....
```

When I save html file using BOM, IE recognizes UTF-8 charset but without BOM, IE doesn't recognize UTF-8 charset(instead, IE use EUC-KR charset automatically).

I must not save my file using BOM because the file has session_start() function on PHP.
Its function doesn't work if it has BOM.

Chrome recognize UTF-8 charset ordinarily.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I take it you're serving this file via a web server, not just double clicking on it? Are you setting HTTP headers properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple - you have typo in your code `"text/html: charset=utf-8"`. You should replace `:` with `;` and get

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

or you can simply use

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

IE8 skipped incorrect meta and guessed wrong encoding.
The more reliable way to set encoding is to send proper headers in php code:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```